# Is Driver exe for New Microsoft Chromium Edge Available?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Does anyone know whether Driver exe for New Microsoft Chromium Edge Available ?

If Yes, please share link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be found here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads

It's version 75 but I've been testing it out and it works fine with Edge 76. Make sure that you have the correct Edge executable on your path depending on whether you have Dev or Canary.

Dev:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\
```

Canary:

```
C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge SxS\Application\
```

There's a bit more info [on my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56134530/514793):

I wouldn't recommend testing Canary, as it's unstable and it changes so fast, maintaining results will not be fun. I'm testing Dev and I'll switch to Beta when that's released.

Just a point regarding Dmitri's answer about market shares:

While accurate, they are global figures, so may be entirely irrelevant to what you're testing. If for example you're developing web applications for businesses, it's not unusual to find that the vast majority of your users are on IE or Edge, because companies have policies about only using Microsoft browsers. Sometimes this is about perceived security, but more often than not, it's about supporting legacy systems and documents, which can only be viewed in IE or chromium Edge's IE mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for automation till official release of the EdgeChromium-based browser from Microsoft, moreover looking into [current browser market share](https://experitest.com/browser-testing/microsoft-is-dropping-edge-cross-browser-testing/) I don't think you should be investing any efforts into it.

> Chrome 61.75%
>
> Safari 15.12%
>
> Firefox    4.92%
>
> UC Browser 4.22%
>
> Opera  3.15%
>
> IE 2.8%
>
> **Edge 2.15%**
>
> Others 5.89%

---

Just in case if you still want to assess the EdgeChromium automation the driver is available since 24th of April 2019 at normal [Edge Driver downloads page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads)

For example direct link for MS Edge 75 driver:

https://msedgecdn.azurewebsites.net/webdriver/index.html