# EdgeWebDriver cannot find Edge browser binary

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run Selenium tests against MS Edge using Java bindings on macOS. I have successfully installed Edge and the Edge Driver. My tests manage to connect to Edge Driver, but it seems the driver cannot locate the browser's binary, see error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Microsoft Edge binary
```

Details:

- Edge version: 77.0.235.9 (latest)
- Edge Driver version: 78.0.253.0 (latest) -- I have also tried 77.0.235.9 to match browser's version
- Selenium version: 3.141.59
- JDK version: 1.8.0_192-b12
- macOS version: 10.14.6

I have seen several questions similar to mine and tried some of the suggested solutions, to no avail. Things I have tried:

- Set environment variable `webdriver.edge.bin` to point to the binary for the browser.
- Using `new EdgeOptions().setBinary()` (not possible since latest version of Java bindings for Selenium doesn't include this method).
- Adding the browser binary to the path.

Comment: Can you try the same code on a Windows host? Does it work there?

Comment: see this for configuring Chromium version of Edge: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/337

Comment: New Edge web driver can only work when initialized as a chrome driver. We use `new ChromeDriver()` when making test with new MS Edge (Chromium). You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076421/selenium-and-edge-dev-chromium-based/56134530#56134530) to see how to run a Selenium test with Java and MS Edge (Chromium).