# Selenium Java on MAC - Edgedriver is not working

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Hi people: I have the next situation.

I want to run automation with Selenium, specifically with Microsoft Edge on Mac.

I have installed **Version 77.0.235.15 (Official build) Beta (64-bit)**

**Edgedriver: Version: 77.0.235.15**

The rest of the browsers run with no drama, but Edgedriver fails.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", Constants.EdgeDriverPath);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.setBinary(Constants.EdgeDriverPath);
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

The error is the next:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from MicrosoftEdge location src/test/resources/drivers/mac/msedgedriver is no longer running, so MSEdgeDriver is assuming that Microsoft Edge has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'CL-IT00331', ip: '192.168.0.12', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   msedgedriver                        0x000000010bc29f99 msedgedriver + 8023961
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please refer to [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), since you are using the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Version: 77.0.235.15, you could download the [correct webDriver version based on the Edge Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuDc1.png).Then, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076421/selenium-and-edge-dev-chromium-based) and [this link](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/337) to use the webdriver.

Comment: Hi: I already downloaded the version that you put in that snapshot. I will the the thread you post. Thanks.