# MSEdgeDriver (Chromium) does not work with version >= 79.0.313 (Canary)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge Webdriver (Chromium) with Python3 in my script.

The webdriver configuration is as follows:

```
driveroptions = Options()
driveroptions.add_argument('--inprivate')
driveroptions.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
driveroptions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driveroptions.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
driveroptions.add_argument('--user-data-dir=D:\\Selenium_Edge_Chromium_UserData')
driveroptions.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge SxS\\Application\\msedge.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=driveroptions, executable_path="msedgedriver.309.exe", service_log_path="D:\\X.txt")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=driveroptions, executable_path="msedgedriver.exe", service_log_path="D:\\X.txt")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
driver.get(base_url)
```

It works well previously, but starting with 79.0.313.0, the driver simply returns the error:

```
Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

And the service log here:

```
[1572262712.029][INFO]: Starting MSEdgeDriver 80.0.315.0 (9e44865e0573123f4459e64bc4e043fee13eb7ec)
[1572262712.029][INFO]: Please protect ports used by MSEdgeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1572262712.567][INFO]: [0b47b609c87652c1d1f004bfac456076] COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--inprivate", "--disable-infobars", "--start-maximized", "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs", "--user-data-dir=D:\\Selenium_Edge_Chromium_UserData" ],
            "binary": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge SxS\\Application\\msedge.exe",
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--inprivate", "--disable-infobars", "--start-maximized", "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs", "--user-data-dir=D:\\Selenium_Edge_Chromium_UserData" ],
         "binary": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge SxS\\Application\\msedge.exe",
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[1572262712.571][INFO]: [0b47b609c87652c1d1f004bfac456076] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

I can still use my script if the msedgedriver version is kept at 79.0.309.0.

But what happened to the newer versions of msedgedriver (79.0.313.0, 80.0.315.0 etc.)?

Are they dropping some supported capabilities?

**Updated**:

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 80.0.315.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 80.0.315.0
->
Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.313.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.313.0
->
Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
->
(Works well without issue)
```

and with 79.0.309.0 (and older) msedgedriver:

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): (version before 79.0.309.0)
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): (version before 79.0.309.0, = browser version)
->
(Works without issue)
```

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
->
(Works without issue)
```

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.313.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
->
(Works without issue)
```

```
Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 80.0.315.0
msedgedriver for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): 79.0.309.0
->
(Works without issue)
```

**PS:**
My GetEdgeDriver.BAT which compares the version of currently installed Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Canary browser with currently downloaded webdriver from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/. If the latter is lower than the former, it downloads the msedgedriver.exe and overwrites the old one.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM GNUWIN32 required

REM SET ONEDRIVE=%UserProfile%\OneDrive
REM This file is located in OneDrive\Files\BIN
SET ONEDRIVE=%~DP0..\..

SET EDGE_DIR=%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge SxS\Application

IF NOT EXIST "%EDGE_DIR%\msedge.exe" ECHO MSEdge not found at %EDGE_DIR%! & GOTO :EOF
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /B "%EDGE_DIR%" ^| grep -E [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.') DO SET MSEDGE_VERSION=%%I& GOTO :MSEDGE_VERSION_RETRIEVED
:MSEDGE_VERSION_RETRIEVED
ECHO MSEdge browser version: %MSEDGE_VERSION%

FOR /F %%I IN ('MSEDGEDRIVER -V ^| awk "{print $2}"') DO SET HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION=%%I& GOTO :HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION_RETRIEVED
:HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION_RETRIEVED
ECHO MSEdge driver version in OneDrive: %HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION%

REM e.g. https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/79.0.287.0/edgedriver_win64.zip
IF %MSEDGE_VERSION% GTR %HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION% (
    SET URL=https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/%MSEDGE_VERSION%/edgedriver_win64.zip
    ECHO.
    ECHO Downloading !URL! -^> %TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip
    REM -C -
    REM continue previous download and skip if existing download
    REM -k --insecure
    curl -C - -s -L -k -o "%TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip" -g "!URL!"
    REM curl -C - -s -L --insecure -o "%TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip" -g "!URL!"
    REM unzip -uoqq "%TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip"
    ECHO Extracting %TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip -^> %~DP0msedgedriver.exe
    REM extract msedgedriver.exe inside edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip to %ONEDRIVE%\Files\BIN folder with the same name
    REM 7z x -y -o"C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Files\BIN" "%TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip" msedgedriver.exe > nul
    7z x -y -o"%ONEDRIVE%\Files\BIN" "%TEMP%\edgedriver_win64_%MSEDGE_VERSION%.zip" msedgedriver.exe > nul

    REM MSEDGEDRIVER -V
    FOR /F %%I IN ('MSEDGEDRIVER -V ^| awk "{print $2}"') DO SET HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION=%%I& GOTO :NEW_DRIVER_VERSION_RETRIEVED
    :NEW_DRIVER_VERSION_RETRIEVED
    ECHO New MSEdge driver version in OneDrive: %HAVE_DRIVER_VERSION%
)
```

Comment: Can you please inform us, what is the current version of your MS Edge (Chromium) browser? I try to check on my side and I am using Edge beta Version 78.0.276.20 I suggest you to download the correct Microsoft WebDriver version for your build of Microsoft Edge (Chromium). If you use any other version than it may give errors. It can be possible that new version of edge driver will work with the version of edge which will update in future. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  I'm using MS Edge (Chromium) Canary 80.0.315.0 and msedgedriver 80.0.315.0 for MS Edge (Chromium). I have a BAT script on my side which compares currently installed browser version with the webdriver version, and they are always kept the same after updating Canary browser. The issue above first happened after the version 79.0.309.0, I remember it should be 79.0.313.0. It still works if I use the old msedgedriver (79.0.309.0 ) with the newest MS Edge (Chromium) Canary browser (80.0.315.0, 2019-10-29). Thanks to everyone who paid attention to this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Hi the question has been updated to provide details and improve readability and yes my script is using the same page with the reference you mentioned.

Comment: Since the official stable version is released at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge (current version 79.0.309.71 on 2020-02-03) we can wait and see whether the newer stable version works with its corresponding driver, instead of focusing on the unstable Canary channel.

Comment: You can test with the stable version and let us know about the results.

Comment: Hi, the title of this page has been updated in order not to mislead people into considering non-Canary versions. The stable version (79.0.309.71) works without issue since it's still 79.0.309.X. @Deepak-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my question.

1. Install/Upgrade Selenium 3.14 to [Selenium 4.0.0a5](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/4.0.0a5/)
2. Change the Python code to something like the following:

```
# using edge directly, since you can see 'selenium.webdriver.chromium.webdriver' used in site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.webdriver import WebDriver
...
...
driveroptions = Options()
# remember to set use_chromium
driveroptions.use_chromium = True
driveroptions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driveroptions.binary_location = env_programfiles_x86 + "\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"

service = Service(executable_path="msedgedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=driveroptions, service=service)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
driver.get(page_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the capabilities like below, it worked, you can have a try:

```
{
    "desiredCapabilities": {
            "nativeEvents": false,
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "version": "",
            "platform": "ANY",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems inside the "alwaysMatch" block IMO. Do you mean launching the webdriver directly with the json file? If so, can you be more specific?

Comment: what I mean is you can try create a session according to [this doc](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#session-1) with a json object made up of `desiredCapabilities` and `requiredCapabilities` and both of them are of type [Capabilities object](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#capabilities-json-object)

Comment: So, I tried again with your payload with the binary path changed, it worked perfectly, are you sure that is the payload you are using and getting errors?

Comment: Have browsed [this](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/), there are a lot of details in there. Haven't tried figuring out how to launch webdriver with json file yet because of busy work. Switching to the 79.0.309.0 webdriver still works (2019-11-11). My direct input is the 1st paragraph of code. The 'service_log_path' parameter in not there when I used my script, it's added after the problem occurred, the X.txt file is created (if not exist) and written when the script started. So I suppose the service log is the output of the webdriver. I will pay attention to it too in a long term. Thanks!

Comment: The 'Beta Channel' is at version 79.0.309.51 and it works well with the corresponding driver. Since the 'Canary Channel' is using version 81, combining it with 79.0.309.0 results in a 'Microsoft Edge version must be 79' error thus the previous workaround with the canary version does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Browser and webdriver must match the first 3 tuples in version number.

In chrome there is a version check that tells you if browser and webdriver does not match. msedge gives the more diffuse: `No matching capabilities found`

I'm using the chocolately `Microsoft Edge Insider - Beta` which installse the msedge browser, it is currently at version 79.0.309.65.

it means I can't use the latest 79.x msedgedriver which currently is at 79.0.313.0, I have to use the 79.0.309.x.

I've implemented a simple test in my selenium driver that check this before starting.

Comment: Actually the release version 80.0.361.57 cannot work with the edge driver (the same version 80.0.361.57) on my Win10 x64, saying "No matching capabilities". However it works indeed with my old msedgedriver.79.0.309.51.exe.

Comment: MSEdgeDriver >80.X has a breaking change. ChromeOptions() has been replaced with EdgeOptions(), this is to be included in selenoum 4.0.0.0a4 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium

Comment: Many thanks for the information! Previous configuraions are seleinum 3.141.0 and Options() from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options. Looking forward to the new stable selenium.