# MS Edge Chromium webdriver crashing starting with 79.309.12

Tags: java, webdriver, microsoft-edge

We are on the MS Edge Chromium dev channel.  Our browser updated automatically to 79.309.12.  We run automated tests using Selenium Webdriver with Java startup.  We downloaded the matching windows x64 driver but now the driver/browser just crashes when we try to start.  The browser comes up and then:

The message is "This page is having a problem" and "Chrome automation extension has crashed"

Our capabilities are basic:

```
    capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions chromeEdgeOpt = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeEdgeOpt.setBinary(System.getProperty("browser.binary"));
    capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeEdgeOpt);
```

where "browser.binary" is the location of the installed msedge.exe binary.  We are setting "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver" to the location of the proper msedgedriver.exe installed on the system.

Anyone have any idea of what changed?  Are there known issues?  I tried the 80.x version as well--same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicated with [MSEdgeDriver (Chromium) does not work after version 79.0.309.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590613/msedgedriver-chromium-does-not-work-after-version-79-0-309-0/58726962#58726962)

Comment: I tried adding these parameters.  It still crashes.  I would like to know what changed?  Is my method of setting up (using ChromeDriver, ChromeOptions) no longer valid?  Plus, I'm not getting a capabilities error--the page just crashes along with a popup bubble saying the ms edge driver crashed.

Comment: Could you provide detailed codes for reproduction of this issue, a minimal reproduceable sample is also good. Feel free to remove any sensitive informations. And what's your system version?

Comment: See the details below.  Still wondering if something fundamental changed internally with the driver around these build numbers

Comment: This is Windows 10, selenium 3.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help.  We run selenium standalone java:

```
java  -jar build/tools/selenium/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role hub -timeout 60 -browserTimeout 60

java  -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=msedgedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -host localhost
```

Then the crash happens when we invoke the RemoteWebDriver, set up with capabilities as above:

```
new RemoteWebDriver(new HttpCommandExecutor("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub", 120000, 10800000), capability);
```

The crash stacktrace is:

```
>> Starting MSEdgeDriver 79.0.309.15 (5ac7eb0eb3bbb495ad3538bf0f49d1bed624cefb) on port 27066
>> Only local connections are allowed.
>> Please protect ports used by the WebDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open window in chrome
>>   (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=79.0.309.15)
>> Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
>> System info: host: 'BMOROZE-US', ip: '10.39.222.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
>> Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>> remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B9085C2+1934786]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B86CA42+1296962]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B7D0941+657729]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B7BE128+581928]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B7682B7+230071]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B76510F+217359]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B74703F+94271]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B74813E+98622]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B88B4D1+1422545]
>>      GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF74B9C9799+655753]
>>      GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF74B9C9531+655137]
>>      GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF74B9D15FC+688108]
>>      GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF74B9C9F73+657763]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B8814CE+1381582]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B88D966+1431910]
>>      Ordinal0 [0x00007FF74B88C7DD+1427421]
>>      BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF850887974+20]
>>      RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF85103A271+33]
>>
>> Command duration or timeout: 1.78 seconds
Failed to invoke configuration method oracle.ojet.automation.test.RichWebDriverBase.setUp:Failed to create instance of Edge Chromium due to an error. Bailing out. The current test will fail.
>> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>>      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>>      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
>>      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
```

Comment: Can you please try the [Selenium 4 alpha2](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0/)?

Comment: That's really not easy for us as we'd have to go through and make some big changes to our Java code to make it compatible with all the 4.0 changes.  Are you saying that all of a sudden MS Edge Chrome webdriver will only support selenium 4.0 alpha?  What changed all of a sudden--it was working fine.