# Chromium Edge browser implementation issue with phpunit-selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge, phpunit

**Environment**

```
OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)
Browser: Microsoft Chromium Edge
Browser version: Version 79.0.309.40 (Official build) beta (64-bit)
Browser Driver version: 79.0.309.40
Language Bindings version: PHP 7.3.3
Selenium Webdriver version: selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1
```

**Running chromium edge web driver**

`java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver=msedgedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar`

**Issue**

I am facing an issue while setting binary path for Chromium edge browser
Below is java code example to set binary path for the same

```
chromeOptions.setBinary(
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe");

EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

Is there any way i can set the same with PHPUnit-Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass path to the binary when starting Selenium server like in [this guide](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/ChromeDriver#run-test-via-selenium-server):

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/msedgedriver.exe
```

Then still use `chrome()` to initiate the browser:

```
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome(); 
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

This approach is similar to the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076421/selenium-and-edge-dev-chromium-based/56134530#56134530) using java. You could have a try.