# What driver do I have to use to run a selenium test in c # on the Edge Chromium browser?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to launch a simple selenium test in c # with the Edge browser, but I can't. The error that indicates me is the following:

**OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The file C: \ Selenium \ Drivers \ MicrosoftWebDriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687**

This is the line of code that gives me the error: `driver = new EdgeDriver ("C:\\Selenium\\Drivers");`

In the path C: \ Selenium \ Drivers I have the following driver: **msedgedriver.exe**

Downloaded from the page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

That driver corresponds to the version I have of the Edge: Microsoft Edge is up to date. **Version 80.0.361.62 (Official compilation) (64 bits)**

What am I doing wrong? What is my error?
How do I solve it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076421/selenium-and-edge-dev-chromium-based) help you?

Comment: You can use [https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools) to have compatibility with Selenium 3, it is available through Nuget, note that the driver is not inside this nuget.

Answer (score 7):

At the time of writing, the Edgedriver downloaded by the nuget package `Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver` is `msedgedriver.exe`, but the `EdgeDriver(...)` constructor is looking for `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`.

I figured out that you can specify the name of the exe like so:

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(
   EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".", "msedgedriver.exe"));
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This helped me and solved another issue I had with Selenium Edge Driver. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

What is the selenium version you're using? If you're using **Selenium 4.00-alpha03 and earlier**, you could refer to the following steps to automate Microsoft Edge Chromium:

- Install the C# Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0 from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).
- Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).
- Example C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;    
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;   
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;       

var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\Drivers", @"msedgedriver.exe"); 
service.UseVerboseLogging = true; 
service.UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true; 
service.Start();  
var caps = new DesiredCapabilities(new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{ 
    { "ms:edgeOptions", new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
        { "binary", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" } 
    }} 
}); 

var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.ServiceUrl, caps);  
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bing.com"); 
Thread.Sleep(2000);  
driver.Close(); 
service.Dispose();
```

**Note:** Change the paths in the code to your owns.

-----------------------------------------------------------------Update-----------------------------------------------------------

You need to use **Selenium 4.00-alpha04** to use the browser-specific options classes when automating Edge Chromium:

- Download the .NET language binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha04 from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-alpha04)
- Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).
- Example C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;  

EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions(false);     
edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"; 
var msedgedriverDir = @"C:\Selenium\Drivers"; 
var msedgedriverExe = @"msedgedriver.exe"; 

var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(msedgedriverDir, msedgedriverExe, false); 
service.EnableVerboseLogging = true; 
var driver = new EdgeDriver(service, edgeOptions); 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bing.com"); 
Thread.Sleep(2000); 
driver.Close();
```

**Note:** Change the paths in the code to your owns.

Comment: Selenium version 3.141.0

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? It is suitable for selenium 3.141.0 and can work well to automate Edge webdriver. I think it's not the wrong driver version, but some mistakes in your code which lead to the error.

Comment: When I write the code you provide me it works correctly, but Visual studio tells me that the use of desiriedCapabilities is deprecated and that I have to use browser-specific options classes

Comment: If you want to use Edge browser-specific options classes, you need to use selenium 4.00-alpha04. Please check my updates. If you use selenium 3.141.0 and use Edge options, it will point to Edge Legacy and use Edge Legacy webdriver MicrosoftWebDriver.exe.

Answer (score 2):

```
driver = new EdgeDriver ("C:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");
```

Please remove unnecessary spaces from the path and also include the .exe file in your path

Comment: I don't have those space. It was a mistake to write it

Comment: if I do this the message just changes to ": The file c:\WebDriver\msedgedriver.exe\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe does not exist"

Comment: Please see my answer.  You do not need to download msedgedriver.exe nor include the path to the exe in the constructor code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to download `msedgedriver.exe` or even know where the PATH to it is.

If you are working with a team or using a build server, it is *much* better to use this NuGet package:

[`Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver/)

It will download the exe for you!  And you do not have to include it in source control.

[These instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) tell how to use Edge/Chromium with Selenium UI Tests, but it does not mention about this very nice NuGet package!

Here is the code from the instructions on how to initialize the driver:

```
        var options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.UseChromium = true;
        var driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `msedgedriver` to `MicrosoftWebDriver`

Copy driver to the path where Edge browser is located. For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application`

Then, use the Edge browser path to initialize the driver:

```
driver = new EdgeDriver ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application");
```