# Selenium Edge WebDriver (Chromium) - session not created: No matching capabilities found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, webdriver-manager

I'm trying to run a Selenium test with Java and Edge driver (based on Chromium).

The version of my Edge Dev installed on `Windows 10` is `83.0.478.37` (Official build dev 64-bit):

Selenium Version : `3.141.59`

I'm using webdrivermanager setup for this and used the example provided [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/EdgeDevTest.java).

I tried many options it includes without using webdriver manager but still gives the error.

**Without Using Webdriver Manager**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")
                            + "\\drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");

EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();

chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
edgeOptions = edgeOptions.merge(chromeOptions);

remDriver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

**AND**
followed other solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076421/selenium-and-edge-dev-chromium-based)

Am i missing something?

The error stack trace below -

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VM-83135Y0-RDS', ip: '10.232.38.151', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE6E1BD2+3414994]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE5B75B2+2192818]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE45477F+739199]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3DF5BF+259519]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3DEEB4+257716]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3E0601+263681]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3DD68F+251535]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3BA663+108131]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE3BB9CE+113102]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE5D24F1+2303217]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AE85E564+1425828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AE85E32A+1425258]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AE8762E1+1523489]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7AE85EB7B+1427387]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE5C8797+2262935]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE5D3ECA+2309834]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7AE5F20C8+2433224]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE43164034+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE453A3691+33]

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:130)
```

Comment: For me I had to updrade selenium package to v4 (I know it's in an alpha stage still). Then for EdgeOptions you will see the UseChromium property - `options.UseChromium = true`. Then pass that into a new EdgeDriver

Comment: `options.UseChromium = true` this is not available in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with little tweaks, and used the [WebdriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/). 
Observed an issue with WebdriverManager, it is downloading a different version of `edgedriver` and eventually it is failing because of the driver/browser incompatibility. 
Check the browser version against the available driver version. If both are different, set the edge driver version like below.

In my scenario -
Edge Browser Version is `84.0.522.49` but its downloading `84.0.524.0`

```
WebDriverManager manager = WebDriverManager.edgedriver();
manager.config().setEdgeDriverVersion("84.0.522.49");
manager.setup();
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting DesiredCapability PLATFORM as WINDOWS instead of WIN10:

capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

You can check the platform by using url:
http://<NODE_HOST>:<YOUR_DRIVER_PORT>/status

replace <NODE_HOST> with your node hostname or ip address and <YOUR_DRIVER_PORT> with port on which driver has been started..

You can easily get this url from node logs if you start node in debug mode by passing -debug while starting node  and then search for line similar to below:

DEBUG [UrlChecker.lambda$waitUntilAvailable$1] - Polling http://localhost:48415/status

http://localhost:48415/status

{"value":{"build":{"version":"88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784})"},"message":"ChromeDriver ready for new sessions.","os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Windows NT","version":"10.0.19041"},"ready":true}}

Even if I am having Windows10 installed, it returns "name":"Windows NT","version":"10.0.19041", hence tried with WINDOWS as platform and it worked perfectly fine!!!